# How can I take a look at the Unicode normalization algorithm in .Net/C# with Mono?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

Dear all, how do I get to peek at the source code for any of the algorithms of .NET? In particular, I'd like to take a look at the unicode normalization algorithm... I'm using Mono in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/SourceCodeRepository):

> The Mono source code is hosted on [GitHub](http://github.com/) using the [Git](http://git-scm.com/) source code control system for all of its source code.
>
> [...]
>
> If all you need is to browse the sources, you can go to [Mono Organization page on GitHub](http://github.com/mono).

The [String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is in the [mscorlib assembly](http://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-2.6.4/mcs/class/corlib/). You can find it in [*/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs*](http://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2.6.4/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs).

[String.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize.aspx) looks like this:

```
public string Normalize ()
{
    return Normalization.Normalize (this, 0);
}

public string Normalize (NormalizationForm normalizationForm)
{
    switch (normalizationForm) {
    default:
        return Normalization.Normalize (this, 0);
    case NormalizationForm.FormD:
        return Normalization.Normalize (this, 1);
    case NormalizationForm.FormKC:
        return Normalization.Normalize (this, 2);
    case NormalizationForm.FormKD:
        return Normalization.Normalize (this, 3);
    }
}
```

The internal *Normalization* class is in [*/mcs/class/corlib/Mono.Globalization.Unicode/Normalization.cs*](http://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2.6.4/mcs/class/corlib/Mono.Globalization.Unicode/Normalization.cs).